# Doctrine join filter

Tags: doctrine-orm

I know conditional filters aren't yet available for queries (as per "26.1.4. Applying Filter Rules to any Query" in the Known Limitations section of the Doctrine2 manual) , so I wanted to ask the experts what their preferred solution to the following problem is:

My site has product objects that each have many reviews.  The reviews have a status field.  I don't want to unnecessarily pull in reviews that haven't been approved during the automatic association that Doctrine2 does so wonderfully.

My current solution/hack is to use single table inheritance (STI) with a discriminator for "status" and have an ApprovedProductReview extending the ProductReview class based on a status of "APPROVED"

I should add that I am currently simply calling 

`$em->find('Entities\Product', $pid);`

to get my product, and Doctrine2 does all the associations automatically.  Should I instead be instantiating a product by providing a DQL query?

What I'd *really* like is a way to override the magic that Doctrine2 provides based on the annotations, and simply be able to use DQL to lazily get the correct subset of reviews.

Suggestions?

Comment: My previous solution was to `filter()` the `ArrayCollection` set using a closure as per the manual, but I felt this was wasteful -- retrieving all that extra data only to filter it out on the php side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `WITH` statement in DQL:

```
$dql = "SELECT p, r
        FROM Entities\Product p
        LEFT JOIN p.reviews r WITH r.status = :status
        WHERE p.id = :id"

$q = $em->createQuery($dql);
$q->setParameter('id', $id);
$q->setParameter('status', $status);
$product = $q->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use a DQL query like this to override the "magic" that Doctrine2 uses when setting up the associations?

Comment: I get it now -- this replaces the "find()" I was using to create the Product before.  Thanks Rojoca!